# Access ssh server behind two routers

Tags: networking, router, ssh, lan

I have setup a private network(Router2) within a network(class C) for TESTING purposes.

Diagram:

```
WAN-->Router1( Gateway 192.168.0.254)-->Lan-->Router2(Sonicwall)-->Lan(10.0.20.1)
```

I have setup so the devices behind Router2 can talk to the internet.

What I would like to do is setup a SSH Server behind Router 2 and connect to that SSH server from another WAN(Home)

Diagram:

```
WAN-->Router1( Gateway 192.168.0.254)-->Lan-->Router2(Sonicwall)-->Lan(10.0.20.1)-->10.0.20.35(SSH Server).
```

So how would I talk to the SSH Server from another WAN(Home) ? Router 1 port forward to Router2 IP? then do a Port forward Router 2 to SSH?

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use the standard SSH port for your SSH server, which is TCP port 22, then you need to forward port 22 from the WAN interface on router 1 to the external interface on router 2, i.e., the IP address on router 2 which faces router 1. Then router 2 needs to forward traffic destined for port 22 on its external interface to 10.0.20.35, which is the IP address you've configured for your SSH server.