# SSH into device attached to another router

Tags: networking, router, ssh, port-forwarding, raspberry-pi

I saw [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1031247/access-ssh-server-behind-two-routers)which looks kind of related, but I'm not sure as the answers are too confusing.

Basically, I want to SSH into my Raspberry Pi from my laptop. Eventually I want to have the Pi talking to the cloud (I want to install a personal VPN on it so I can be protected while traveling and just to learn).

[image]

Now, before you ask why I have two wireless routers on my home network, Router A is for a home office and due to the lead in the walls separating the office from the home (part of the office was once an X-Ray room), the wireless signal doe snot propagate. So it's mainly used as a firewall and to connect the office desktop to the web. Router B does the heavy lifting.

Now, I've set up the network as such (I don't know much about networking, but of the little I do, I managed to build this setup). However, in my reading, I understand that I need to forward a port, namely port 22 for the Pi. But on which end? Which router forwards the port? And is there a better way to do this in general? I'm open to suggestions.

Just for the record, the two routers are identical, [TRENDNet TEW-812DRU v1](https://www.trendnet.com/langen/support/supportdetail.asp?prod=100_TEW-812DRU)

Answer (score 0):

If you can enable IP Forwarding on Router B, you could have the problem solved. After looking into the TEW-812DRU's settings (on their [virtual](https://www.trendnet.com/emulators/TEW-812DRU_V1.0R/) settings page), here's how to do so:
To enable IP forwarding:
Go to Advanced, then the Routing sub-menu, then enter the Router A LAN network information on one of the LAN Static Routes entries (for example - IP: 192.168.10.102, Mask: 255.255.255.0, Gateway: 192.168.10.1, Metric: 24. You may have to change these, let me know)

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Says `metric` must be between 1 and 15

Comment: I do see `virtual server rules` under `Firewall`, perhaps that's what we're looking for? But I put the info in there (port 22, TCP, 192.168.10.102) and I get an error: `IP address does not in LAN subnet.` (yes, it makes no grammatical sense...)

Comment: Try switching the entry into the WAN Static Routes. And switch the metric somewhere in between 1 and 15.